# Unlock edit configuration in panel admin

Tags: magento2

In the configuration in the administration panel I have the option of editing the value blocked. Anyone know how to unlock it? I can't edit most settings

https://i.stack.imgur.com/pZjzl.jpg

Answer (score 0):

The options are currently greyed out because the `Use Website` option is currently checked.

To enable the select dropdowns, simply uncheck the `Use Website` options.